# Trying To Print Out All The Names Of The Processes And Their PID In Kernel Mode

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, kernel

I am trying to print all the names of the processes and their PID.
But when I print the PID, it doesn't print it.

It does print all the other stuff and everything else is working.

I think the problem is that I am trying to convert `fileName` to `wchar_t*`.

Can someone help me, please?

```
int getPIDByName(wchar_t* name) {
    PEPROCESS ep;
    if (::PsLookupProcessByProcessId(::PsGetCurrentProcessId(), &ep) == STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER) {
        ObDereferenceObject(ep);
        DbgPrint("Can't get EPROCESS");
        return STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    }

    PUNICODE_STRING Path = NULL;
    ::SeLocateProcessImageName(ep, &Path);
    PLIST_ENTRY Process_List_Entry = ((LIST_ENTRY*)((LPBYTE)ep + 0x448));
    PLIST_ENTRY List_Entry = Process_List_Entry->Flink;
    LPBYTE pUpi;
    DbgPrint("Starting with buffer path: %wZ", Path);
    while (Path->Buffer == NULL) {
        DbgPrint("The buffer is null so going forward to next process: %wZ", Path);
        pUpi = ((LPBYTE)List_Entry) - 0x448;
        ep = ((PEPROCESS)pUpi);
        ::SeLocateProcessImageName(ep, &Path);
        List_Entry = List_Entry->Flink;
    }

    DbgPrint("1.The path is: %wZ", Path);
    while (wcsstr(Path->Buffer, name) == NULL && Process_List_Entry != List_Entry->Flink) {
        pUpi = ((LPBYTE)List_Entry) - 0x448;
        ep = ((PEPROCESS)pUpi);
        ::SeLocateProcessImageName(ep, &Path);
        DbgPrint("2. The path is: %wZ", (const wchar_t*)Path);
        List_Entry = List_Entry->Flink;
    }
    if (Process_List_Entry == List_Entry->Flink) {
        DbgPrint("%wZ isn't running quiting!", name);
        return STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }
    pUpi = ((LPBYTE)List_Entry->Blink) - 0x448 + 0x440;
    int UniqueProcessId = *((int*)pUpi); //Notepad PID
    DbgPrint("The PID of %ls is %d\n", name, UniqueProcessId);
    return UniqueProcessId;
}


NTSTATUS PrintPID() {
    PEPROCESS EP;
    if (::PsLookupProcessByProcessId(::PsGetCurrentProcessId(), &EP) == STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER) {
        ObDereferenceObject(EP);
        DbgPrint("Can't get EPROCESS");
        return STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    }
    UCHAR* fileName = { 0 };
    UCHAR* processFileName;

    LIST_ENTRY list_entry = *((LIST_ENTRY*)((LPBYTE)EP + 0x448));
    processFileName = ((UCHAR*)(LPBYTE)list_entry.Flink - 0x448 + 0x5a8);
    DbgPrint("%s", processFileName);
    list_entry = *list_entry.Flink;

    while (fileName != processFileName) {
        fileName = ((UCHAR*)(LPBYTE)list_entry.Flink - 0x448 + 0x5a8);
        if (fileName[0] == 'N' || fileName[0] == 'n') {
            DbgPrint("Test");
            DbgPrint("The PID is %d\n" , getPIDByName((wchar_t*)fileName));
        }
        list_entry = *list_entry.Flink;
    }
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using these lower-level APIs, and not higher-level APIs like `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`+`Process32(First|Next)()`, or at least `EnumProcesses()`+`OpenProcess()+QueryFullProcessImageName()`?

Comment: What does "when I print the PID, it doesn't print it" mean?  You get no output?  You get output but not containing the line starting "The PID"?  You get that line but no number?  You get that line and it contains a number but the number is not the one you expected?

Comment: I am using lower-level APIs because I want to practice. "when I print the PID, it doesn't print it" means that I get that line but no number.

Comment: I don't know what's going on with these weird magic constants: `0x448 + 0x5a8`, but is `fileName` actually formatted in UTF-16LE? If not, the cast to `wchar_t*` will produce bad results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ZwQuerySystemInformation to get a list of all processes. From that list you can get all the names and process ids.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).